# How can I test if a string contains 0 or 1, then convert it from binary to decimal?

Tags: java

I have to create a conversion method that analyzes if the characters in a string are 1 and/or 0, then include that character in a conversion from binary to decimal. Then I have to use a try-catch block to prompt the user for a binary number, and convert the number within the try-catch block and print the converted number to the console. Right now, I can't seem to get the code to return the converted decimal, or the BinaryFormatException.

This is what I have so far:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String binaryString;
        int decimalNumber = 0;

        try {
            System.out.print("Please enter the binary number to convert: ");
            binaryString = input.nextLine();
            convertBinary(String.valueOf(decimalNumber));
            System.out.println("Your number converted to decimal is " + binaryString + ".");
        } catch (BinaryFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    static int convertBinary(String binaryString) throws BinaryFormatException {
        int decimalNumber = 0;
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < binaryString.length(); i++) {
            if (binaryString.matches("[01]+")) {
                throw new BinaryFormatException("Improper formatting for character: " + i + ".");
            }
            else {
                int temp = i%10;
                decimalNumber += temp*Math.pow(2, i);
                i = i/10;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the part you are having trouble with? checking whether it is binary, or converting it? I would suggest checking if there aren't already methods to perform those tasks.

Comment: @Stultuske - I have edited the post to explain my problem. I can't seem to get the code to return the converted decimal, or return the thrown exception to the console.

Comment: e.g. via regular expression `str.matches("^[01]+$")`

Comment: You can start off by actually passing the `binaryString` to the `convertBinary` method.

Answer (score 1):

you missed return statement...
i suggest you use a ide, not a notepad

```
static int convertBinary(String binaryString) throws BinaryFormatException {
        int decimalNumber = 0;
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < binaryString.length(); i++) {
            if (binaryString.matches("[01]+")) {
                throw new BinaryFormatException("Improper formatting for character: " + i + ".");
            }
            else {
                int temp = i%10;
                decimalNumber += temp*Math.pow(2, i);
                i = i/10;
                i++;
            }
        }
        **return decimalNumber;**
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Your "convertBinary" method has no return value, you need to return an Integer.

2."BinaryFormatException" is a custom Exeption, you need to make a class for it like this:

```
private static class BinaryFormatException extends Exception {
    public BinaryFormatException(String err){
        super(err);
    }
}
```

3.You can use the parseInt method of Ineger to convert to decimal, since it supports numeral systems as second parameter e.g.:

```
int i=Integer.parseInt("11", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use standard lib from Java.
Also be careful about the length of the `binaryString`. If too long, then it cannot be parsed to int and you might need to use long.

```java
        String binaryString = "111001111111111";
        if (binaryString.length() >= 31) {
            // don't forget to check the string length
            //
            // throw some error, or use long instead of integer
        }
        try {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(binaryString, /* radix */ 2);
            System.out.println(value);        // 29695
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            // binaryString contains something that is not 1 or 0
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Enter binary:");
        String stringOfBinary = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        int decimalNumber = convertToDecimal(stringOfBinary);
        System.out.println("Your number converted to decimal is " + decimalNumber + ".");
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException bfe)
    {
        System.out.println(bfe);
    }
}

static int convertToDecimal(String binary) throws NumberFormatException
{
    if (!binary.matches("^[0-1]*$"))
        throw new NumberFormatException("Improper formatting for input string: "+binary);

    return Integer.valueOf(binary, 2);
}
```

Make sure you replace NumberFormatException with your exception.